# TIDHTTP : Could not load SSL library on non https URLs

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I'm using TIDHTTP to download a zip file from a non https url, like the code below :

```
IdHTTPProgress.DownloadFile('http://www.myurl.com/myfile.zip','c:\myfile.zip');
```

Nevertheless i'm getting the exception 'Could not load SSL library'. The exception happens but after that the download is made anyway.

How can i avoid this exception ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that exception can happen is when:

- you have assigned a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component to the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` property.

  It will attempt to initialize OpenSSL, even if you are making an HTTP request, as the potential exists for any HTTP request to redirect to HTTPS, so Indy prepares OpenSSL when establishing a TCP connection, just in case.
- you have not deployed the OpenSSL DLLs (`libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`, or equivalent for your target platform) with your app - OR - you have deployed the *wrong* version of the DLLs that are not compatible with your version of Indy.

  If you are going to use `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, you need the proper DLLs.  Indy currently supports up to OpenSSL 1.0.2, but not OpenSSL 1.1.0 or later (yet - that is [on the TODO list](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183)).

When Indy raises the "Could not load SSL library" exception, you can then call Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to find out if the failure is because the DLLs failed to load into memory, or because the DLLs are missing exports that Indy requires.

There is also an `OpenSSLVersion()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSL` unit to report which version of OpenSSL has been loaded into memory.

In your case, no redirect from HTTP to HTTPS happens, but the error still occurs internally, which `TIdHTTP` swallows since HTTPS is not being used.  Your code will not see the exception at runtime. But your debugger will.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Remy, but the IOHandler property is blank on my TIDTTP. And indeed i don't deploy OpenSSL DDLs, because i'm not using https, so in theory, i'd not need it. The exception happens only while debugging. So i'm supposed to ignore it ?

Comment: @delphirules The exception is raised by `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`. If you leave the `IOHandler` nil, `TIdHTTP` creates a default one internally, either `TIdIOHandlerStack` or `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, based on whether the 1st request is HTTP or HTTPS (but only if `IdSSLOpenSSL` is in your `uses` clause). Once set, the `IOHandler` does not change automatically. You can't request an HTTP url and get an SSL load error unless `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` were already set beforehand.

Comment: @delphirules And if `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` were not set, and a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS occured, you would get a different exception ("IOHandler is not valid"). But yes, if the exception is being swallowed by `TIdHTTP` and does not reach your code, then you can ignore it. And optionally tell the debugger to ignore it, too. If you don't want to use HTTPS at all, you should not have any reference to the `IdSSLOpenSSL` unit in your project.